# how to add icons in Payzippy sand box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway

1. Is is possible to add icons in the Pay zippy sand box page??
2. If yes what should I do to do this in the API ?? I am working on .net

   ```
    SortedDictionary<string, string> hashParameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

       hashParameters.Add("merchant_key_id", Constants.PaymnetGateways.PayZippy.MERCHANT_KEY_ID);
       hashParameters.Add("hash_method", "MD5");
       hashParameters.Add("merchant_transaction_id", invoice.InvoiceNumber.ToString());
       hashParameters.Add("transaction_amount", (totalAmount * 100).ToString("##0"));
       hashParameters.Add("transaction_type", "SALE");
       hashParameters.Add("buyer_phone_no", phone);
       hashParameters.Add("ui_mode", "REDIRECT");
       hashParameters.Add("merchant_id", Constants.PaymnetGateways.PayZippy.MERCHANT_ID);
       hashParameters.Add("currency", "INR");
       hashParameters.Add("buyer_email_address", companyAdmin.UserName);
       hashParameters.Add("callback_url", Constants.PaymnetGateways.PayZippy.RETURN_URL);
       hashParameters.Add("payment_method", "DEBIT");
       hashParameters.Add("item_name", "Membership at Hrstop.com");

       string SharedSecretKey = Constants.PaymnetGateways.PayZippy.MERCHANT_SHARED_SECRET_KEY;
       //merchant_key_id=payment hash_method=SHA256 hash=ignore_this merchant_transaction_id=MT123 transaction_amount=100 
       //transaction_type=SALE buyer_phone_no=9999999999 ui_mode=IFRAME merchant_id=test_merchant payment_method=CREDIT 
       //currency=INR buyer_email_address=email@email.com           

       string temp = string.Join("|", hashParameters.Values);
       temp += "|" + SharedSecretKey;
       Log.LogDebug("PayThroughPayZippy: String to be hashed: " + temp);
       string hash = Utility.CalculateMD5Hash(temp);
       Log.LogDebug("PayThroughPayZippy: Hashed Value: " + hash);

       RemotePostCCAvenue postForm = new RemotePostCCAvenue();
       postForm.Url = Constants.PaymnetGateways.PayZippy.CHARGING_POST_URL;

       foreach (string key in hashParameters.Keys)
           postForm.Add(key, hashParameters[key]);

       postForm.Add("hash", hash);

       // Log.LogDebug(string.Format("Invoice Id :{0}, Amount: {1}, Redirect_Url: {2}, Checksum: {3}", order.InvoiceNumber, storeOrderDetails.CCAvanueDisplayAmount.ToString(), WEBConstants.PaymentGateway.PayZippy.RETURN_URL, hash));
       string form = postForm.GetPostForm();
       Log.LogDebug("Form: " + form);
       return form;
   ```

Comment: What language are you using? And please, try to format your code, we can't do anything with this dump.

Comment: hi I am working on Mvc3

Comment: I want to add my company logo at the pay zippy page where we fill the card details